# Keep having Run-time error '53' pop up window when opening Microsoft Office 2021 Word, Power point or Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

Keep having Run-time error '53' pop up window when opening Microsoft Office 2021 Word, Power point or Excel. I have reinstalled the Office completely and tried other different suggested solutions but nothing helped. It looks like I have to live with this stupid bug for the rest of my life ! Despite there are a few pieces of advice on how to resolve this bug but nothing helps for me.

Run-time error '53': File not found: /Library/Application Support/Adobe/ MACPDFM/MacPDFM.framework/Versions/A/MacPDFM

Comment: You are on a Mac? This appears to be connected to an Adobe add-in. Try disabling the Add-In.

Comment: See some help for this here https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/407353/253299

Comment: Thanks, yes disabling add-ins seems to be the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended that you start your Mac in Safe Mode, which excludes the impact of the environment. If the Office app opens normally after booting your Mac in Safe Mode, you need to disable the Office add-in.

Comment: Yes that's the case, Thanks!